# Disable UITableViewCell selection by touch but enable by method call

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, touches

What is the best way of preventing the user from selecting a cell inside a UITableView, but allowing my program to call `selectRowAtIndexPath:` on the table view?

I also want the controls in the UITableViewCell to remain interactive (i.e. allow `touchesBegan:` to be called on the UITableViewCell).

If I do `[tableView setAllowsSelection:NO]`, calling `selectRowAtIndexPath:` does not do anything.

Comment: Set userInteraction to No for table view and then try to call selectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Unfortunately, that will not pass any touches to the cell. It will not call `touchesBegan:` on the cell.

Comment: Ohk. Can you brief why you want to stop default cell selection and give custom selection with touchesBegan?

Comment: I want the cell to show certain buttons when the cell is tapped. Then, if one of the buttons in the cell is pressed, I want to set the cell as selected.

Comment: why don't you track this by button's action? if a particular button is pressed then select the cell else don't.

Comment: First of all, the button will not appear until the cell is tapped once. So, in `touchesBegan:` I show the button if it is not already shown. Then, if the button is tapped, I programmatically call `selectRowAtIndexPath:`. However, by default table view behavior, the `selectRowAtIndexPath:` would have already been called on the initial tap of the cell.

Comment: Do you want to select another row after you tap the button, since the cell is already in a selected state.

Comment: You can call _deselectRowAtIndexPath:_ as soon as the _didSelectRowAtIndexPath:_ get called and then you can show your custom buttons. When button is pressed you may call _selectRowAtIndexPath:_ as intended.

Comment: @Gandalf Won't calling `selectRowAtIndexPath:` programmatically call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, which will deselect it? I want it to stay selected if called programmatically.

Comment: @golddove - No, it won't. The cell will remain selected after this.

Comment: Oh ok, I just realized that the delegate methods don't get called if you call `selectRowAtIndexPath:`. I posted a slightly different way of achieving the same thing, but yours works too! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realized that when you call `selectRowAtIndexPath:` programmatically, then the delegate method `willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` will not be called. However, if a user taps a cell, then this will be called. This method can return nil to prevent selection.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return nil;
}
```

This will ensure that only programmatic calls to `selectRowAtIndexPath:` will select a row and any taps to select a row will not.

Comment: You can also do one thing, 
1. Setting the delegate of uitableview object to nil on touches began and
2. Again setting delegate to self when touch ended.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the box : User Interaction Enabled in TableView as well as TableViewCell

[image]

Comment: The controls in the `UITableViewCell` will not remain interactive and `touchesBegan:` will not be called on it.